# Error when starting a local server on Mkdocs Windows, how do I fix?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, mkdocs

I am trying to edit some docs on github, here are my instructions:

1. Clone the repo
2. Create a virtual environment
3. Install dependencies
4. Start a local server

I am able to 1 and 2 no problem, and 3 installs: mkdocs and mkdocs-material

I run into an issue on #4 with an error:
"ERROR    -  Config value: 'pages'. Error: The configuration option 'pages' was removed from MkDocs. Use 'nav' instead.
Aborted with 1 Configuration Errors!"

The MkDocs website does state this:
"Breaking change: the pages config option that was deprecated for a very long time now causes an error when used (#2652)

To fix the error, just change from pages to nav."

I am not a dev, so not sure what changing pages to nav means. There are some files named pages, but changing to nav would be nav(2).

How would I fix this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

So MkDocs no longer supports the 'pages' tag on generating the site. The replacement for it is called 'nav'.

So all you have to do generally is replace 'pages' in your mkdocs with 'nav' and that should fix it